# Is Philip in Acts 8 the deacon or the disciple?

Tags: acts, referent-identification

I would like to know if the Philip who baptized the eunuch in Acts 8 is Philip the disciple or the deacon mentioned in Acts 6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. If you haven't done so already, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://goo.gl/5U2gsX) and read up on how this site is a [little different](http://goo.gl/wCxRAv) than other sites around the web. [Great](http://goo.gl/yBdAcO) [question!](http://goo.gl/18PZou)

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be commonly held that Philip referred to here is the same as the deacon in chapter 6. The twelve disciples while they are mentioned in the book of Acts do not seem to be as much in the lime light. Peter is a major player in the first part of Acts and Paul, though not one of the twelve, in the second. The Philip spoken of in chapter 8 is clearly an evangelist in light of the ministry he performed. In Acts 21 we read of Philip the evangelist who was one of the seven deacons. And interestingly enough his residence is in Caesarea where Philip in chapter 8 ended up at the conclusion of his evangelistic tour. I would say the Philip referred to chapter 6, 8, and 21 is the same person. The deacon not the disciple.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics SE, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://goo.gl/5U2gsX) to learn more about us. We're a [little different](http://goo.gl/wCxRAv) from other SEs. Our community looks for answers to reflect a good degree of research and references. Typically, we like answers that [cite scholarly references](http://goo.gl/VRkT4c) and/or explain how your interpretation arises from the text. Don't just tell us [*what*](http://goo.gl/VRkT4c) you know, tell us [*how*](http://goo.gl/BoMPLJ) you know it.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly think that Philip in Acts 8 is one of the sevens chosen in Acts 6. This thought based on the preceding narration in Acts 8:1, "**except the Apostles**".

Comment: Good contextual clue!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Philip chosen as deacon in Acts 6 is the same Philip who preached in Samaria and converted Simon Magus (Acts 8:9-13), and later the Ethiopian eunuch.  In Acts 21:8, Luke later refers to Philip as *the evangelist* (ὁ εὐαγγελιστής), and *one of the seven*.

---

Augustine wrote:

> Philip the deacon is mentioned in the Acts of the Apostles as having
> been chosen among the seven; and he it was that baptized the eunuch of
> Queen Candace, and preached Christ in Samaria (*Tractate* XXXVI.5 on Acts)

Commenting on Acts 8:26ff, John Chrysostom makes reference to the fact that the Angel of the Lord directed Philip to go south and not north:

> It seems to me, this Philip was one of the seven; for from Jerusalem
> he would not have gone southwards, but to the north; but from Samaria
> it was *towards the south* (*Homily XIX on Acts*).

---

Tradition held that this Philip was later sent to Tralles in Asia Minor and that he died in old age.

Answer (score 1):

Acts 6:

> 5
> This proposal pleased the whole group. They chose **Stephen** [1], a man full of faith and of the Holy Spirit; also **Philip** [2], Procorus [3], Nicanor [4], Timon [5], Parmenas [6], and Nicolas [7] from Antioch, a convert to Judaism.

Philip was #2 in this list of seven.

Persecution came, Acts 8:

> 1b On that day a great persecution broke out against the church in Jerusalem, and all **except the apostles** were scattered throughout Judea and Samaria. 2Godly men buried **Stephen** and mourned deeply for him.

Stephen the #1 on the list of seven was dead. Apostles stayed put. Others were scattered.

> 4 Those who had been scattered preached the word wherever they went. 5 **Philip** went down to a city in Samaria and proclaimed the Messiah there.

Philip the #2 on the list left Jerusalem. He didn't want to stick around and get stoned to death like his predecessor.

The Bible does not explicitly mention that this Philip is one of the Seven but it is likely that he is based on the following two contextual clues:

1. Philip was not an apostle.
2. Philip was #2 in the list of Seven right after Stephen.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe the Philip of Chapter 8 is the Apostle every time we have 2 men with the same Name In the same Time Period especially Luke always identifies one of them differently so base  on Chap 21 Luke describes this Philip as an evangelist Philip the Evangelist was selected in Chapt 6 so by reason in chap 8 we now have 2 men named Philip I believe Luke would have used the pharse the evangelist and or one of the 7 to identify Philip of vhapt 8 if it was the later. The phase except the deciples to me is not clear enough to identify Philip as the evangelist of chapter 8. We also note that Philip of chapter 8 was called by Jesus to the eunuch by Jesus from Jerusalem in vs 26 so not scattered as mentioned in vs 1, one other note as we see Philip in Jerusalem after the trip to Samaria again in vs 25 it would seem Samaria was considered local to Jerusalem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The Phillip of Acts 8 was most likely the Apostle and not the deacon described in Acts 6 as is commonly held.  One need only look at the reason the deacons in Acts 6 were chosen.  Acts 6:2-4 make it clear that they were chosen to free up the Apostles for preaching the word.  God knew the Apostles needed a nudge to leave Jerusalem.  Gaza and Azotus were not far way anyway.  Finally Luke called the book Acts of the Apostles, not Acts of the Deacons or Acts of the Disciples  or Acts of the Evangelists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Madison Laird Hi Madison, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!